# How do make my submit button start a JQ function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How do I make my submit button in a form, start a JQ function?. So far I made Dreamweaver start a whole JS file but not a specific function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onclick` attribute on the button

```
<button onclick='functionName()'>
```

Comment: Gives me a either a "not found" or just doesnt do anything

Comment: @Blackwolf23 Make sure the function you call exists

Comment: I did its there still of no use

Comment: Well It worked one one html file like it is supposed to, while on the other one it doesnt. The problem is most likely related to my script placing

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript code in

```
$(document).ready({

   $('#contactForm').submit(function() {

      //Do stuff here

   }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the "onclick" attribute like that

`<button onclick="myFunction()">submit</button>`

and you should have the `myFunction()` defined in script tags for example:

`<script>`

`myFunction() {your code}`

`</script>`

or the `myFunction()` found in the js file.